# Alignment question on ARM binary

Tags: c, arm, alignment

Here I am back again with a confused mind! :)

As I had understood the usual alignment of data by armcc will be as below (taken from ARM site)
[ARM Compiler toolchain Using the Compiler: Types of data alignment](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472c/CJAJDDHB.html)

But in my binary I see print_quality{} structure instance residing at 0x205B387

**[D:0x205B387] print_quality** = ((0x44, 0x72, 0x61, 0x66, 0x74, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0

Here sizeof(print_quality) = 0x1E

The structure being
char print_quality[][10] = {
    "Draft",
    "Normal",
    "High"
};

And later in the flow I am getting crash while executing

***ldrh    r2,[r1] ; Here r1=02064769***

So I guess its crashing because of reading from mis-aligned address!?

What is going wrong!? :(
Any thoughts are welcome..

BR,

/MS

Comment: Can you add some more context? The information here is not sufficient to answer your question. For instance, how is your `print_quality` structure defined? And what is the C code that is compiling to the `ldrh` instruction you mention?

Comment: Sorry! crash might be for a different reason. But what I am puzzled is print_quality residing at odd adress despite being its size being 30 bytes

Comment: ok Martin added the structure and got the answer as well.. its strucure of chars! that can justify residing at odd address! :) and we can ignore the crash at ldrh. i think it was pointer going beyond array boundary. the c line is   for ( ; *p != 0 ; ++p )
;

Comment: Just a note: You're using the word "structure" with a broader meaning than it has in the C language. Your `print_quality` is an array, _not_ a structure; in C, a structure is a data type that is defined using the `struct` keyword, and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, this usually happens because of casting from one thing to another (for example, using byte-aligned array and copying into it the structs, I've made that mistake myself plenty of times). I'm not sure you can get any definitive answer without actually showing your code, but if you have a `void*` somewhere in the execution path, or a `memcpy` that would be a culprit.

Comment: yes agreed. My bad today.. I got too many things not proper.. Thanks all for your inputs.. :)